# Enter animation not playing in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I'm wondering how could I animate an element when the angular app is starting.

Indeed, I see (I'm maybe doing something wrong) that the animation module is not triggering the "enter" event the first time, but after everything goes fine. How could I animate it without rewriting all the code I have in my animation module somewhere else ?

You can see on my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avOff/q3mQh/3/) that the li is green at first glance, when I need it to be blue as defined in my enter animation.

I don't know if it only occurs in my configuration which is the following :

```
<li ng-if="$index === value" ng-repeat="proj in projects" class="test-anim">test</li>
```

, animating the test-anim class.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in 1.2.3. See this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5130

You could use a timeout like this to try to wait until the page is rendered before adding data to your ng-repeats/ng-if:

```
$timeout(function(){
        $scope.value = 0;
        $scope.projects = [{}, {}, {}];      
    }, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @dtabuenc for helping. In fact, I can't get this works as long as I put my ng-if directive as a child of ng-repeat. Otherwhile, it will indeed work. I tried using $timeout or setting empty value without success. Here is a [link] illustrating (http://jsfiddle.net/avOff/HQ4vc/). The only difference between the one I post in the question and this one is that ng if is now a child...